# Images from main bundle cannot be loaded in WKWebView(on Device, but simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
let baseURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
webView.loadHTMLString("<img src=\"img.png\" />", baseURL: baseURL)
```

img.png can be loaded on simulator, but cannot be loaded on my iPhone.
What's up?

Comment: The simulator is most likely on a case insensitive file system, whereas the device isn't. Check the spelling of your file and see if it really matches.

Comment: @JustSid , I loaded a html file from main bundle for WKWebView to render, it worked fine. And I'm sure that the name of image is correct.

Comment: This seems like a bug, I have just hit it, too. :-/ Could you resolve it somehow? https://openradar.appspot.com/20379146